# How to make a custom control with different interaction methods for mouse and keyboard?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I want to make a custom control that has different interaction methods for mouse and keyboard. More specifically, it will have buttons for mouse use and separate keyboard controls, similar to the native number input.

In essence, there are action two buttons ("decrement" and "increment") and a value. The control itself is the focusable part; the buttons are not keyboard focusable, they can only be clicked. When the control is focused, the up/down arrow keys trigger the same actions as the buttons.

Here's the basic *structure* I have at the moment (no labels, ARIA, etc.):

```html
<span id="control">
  <button data-action="decrement"> - </button>
  <span data-value>0</span>
  <button data-action="increment"> + </button>
</span>
```

Below is a very minimal implementation that simply uses the two buttons:

```js
const control = document.querySelector("#control");
const buttonDecrement = control.querySelector('[data-action="decrement"]');
const buttonIncrement = control.querySelector('[data-action="increment"]');
const value = control.querySelector("[data-value]");

function decrement() {
  value.textContent = Number(value.textContent) - 1;
}

function increment() {
  value.textContent = Number(value.textContent) + 1;
}

buttonDecrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  decrement();
});

buttonIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  increment();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

[data-value] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: calc(3ch + 1em);
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<span id="control">
  <button data-action="decrement" aria-label="Decrement">
    -
  </button>
  <span data-value>0</span>
  <button data-action="increment" aria-label="Increment">
    +
  </button>
</span>
```

Now, what I need help with:

- The focus should always go to the container, not the contents (except maybe for things like arrow key navigation with a screen reader?).
  `tabindex="0"` on the container and `-1` on the buttons seems to work, but there is likely more to it that I'm missing.
  Then there's the issue of nested interactive elements, etc. I'm not sure what the "correct" behavior is.
  UPDATE: As per the [WAI ARIA spec for the `spinbutton` role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#spinbutton), a spinbutton may have a textbox and two buttons as children/owned elements; so I believe this is okay.

  > Authors **MAY** create a `spinbutton` with children or owned elements, but **MUST** limit those elements to a `textbox` and/or two `buttons`. Alternatively, authors **MAY** apply the `spinbutton` role to a text input and create sibling buttons to support the increment and decrement functions.

  However, the [WAI ARIA example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/spinbutton/examples/datepicker-spinbuttons/) and [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/spinbutton_role#examples) both have the buttons as siblings, so I'm not sure which method is actually preferred?
- I experimented with adding keyboard event listeners (in conjunction with applying `tabindex`), but when using a screen reader (NVDA, specifically) the events were consumed by it instead of triggering the event listener. For example, the arrow keys are used for navigation; standard controls that use these (the number input uses the up/down arrows, for example) are fine, but I don't know how to specify that behavior for my own event listeners.
  UPDATE: I later found this is due to NVDA's browse mode: [nvaccess/nvda#11630 (Keydown event not triggered on button element when NVDA is open)](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/11630). When the `spinbutton` role is applied, [NVDA switches from browse mode to focus mode when focusing it](https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvda/documentation/userGuide.html#BrowseMode) (arrow key navigation does not focus it). So this is okay now.
- It should be reasonably accessible, or able to be made so.
  For example:

  - It should have labeling. Based on [the docs for `aria-label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-label#associated_roles), I understand a role is required for this. However, I am not sure which to use.
    UPDATE: [As suggested by @QuentinC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77204511/15261914), this control is a spinbutton.
  - A screen reader should read the value when focusing it, but not list the buttons. Just using `aria-hidden` on the buttons *seems* to work.
    UPDATE: The WAI ARIA and MDN examples have the buttons as siblings and *not hidden*; they also have `aria-label`. This means that they are announced when clicked. I'm not sure what the best/recommended method is here.
  - The new value should be read out it is updated. I believe `aria-live` is enough?
    UPDATE: The `spinbutton` role has a corresponding `aria-valuenow` attribute for the value, which includes this behavior when updated.
  - The keyboard controls should be made known to accessibility technology somehow.
    UPDATE: The `spinbutton` role has well-known controls.

One hard requirement is that the buttons can have custom content inserted. Specifically, a custom element that displays an SVG icon.

Custom elements can be used. However, the Element Internals API is not widely supported enough, so please don't include that as a requirement, unless stating that there is no other way.

---

Background:

The project in question is song chord sheet viewer. Although there is some desktop use, the app is predominantly used on mobile.

The primary case is a collection of controls for the viewer itself. There is a control each for text size, scroll speed (for automatic scroll), and transpose amount. The text size has a step size of 2, a lower bound of 2, and no upper bound, but shouldn't ever need to go above about 40. The scroll speed has a step size of 5 (although that may be changed soon), a lower bound of 5, and no upper bound, but shouldn't ever need to go above about 50. The transpose has a step size of 1, a lower bound of -11, an upper bound of 11, and wraps back to zero when crossing a bound.

The original implementation simply had the two buttons, as in the included demo.

To be clear, I am not against allowing typed input. There are two original reasons that it uses just the stepper buttons without a type-in input:

- The first was (likely overly) strict requirements for valid values and step sizes
- The second was that the implementation for the stepper was value agnostic: it simply displayed the value and emitted events for decrementing and incrementing; the consumer decided what to do on these inputs. The final logic was rather abstracted, with there being the stepper control, a wrapper component, and a data controller that exposed actions.

So, it mainly comes down to the structure of the existing codebase. The stepper was not intended to handle the values itself, only to notify the controller of requested changes. The controller is also used by separate keyboard hotkeys, and potentially touch gestures in the future, so it's not that simple to change. Although, if the touch gestures are implemented as continuous, sliding gestures instead of a swipe/tap/whatever per step, it may be a case to put in the work to change the controller to instead take raw values and normalize them...

---

**UPDATE**

The following is a basic version of what I have as of 2023-10-02.

```js
const container = document.querySelector("#container")
const buttonDecrement = document.querySelector('[data-action="decrement"]')
const buttonIncrement = document.querySelector('[data-action="increment"]')
const valueEl = document.querySelector("[data-value]")

const label = document.querySelector('label[for="container"]')
container.setAttribute("aria-label", label.textContent)

const setValue = (value) => {
  valueEl.textContent = value
  container.setAttribute("aria-valuenow", value)
}

setValue(Number(valueEl.textContent))

const focus = () => {
  if (container === document.activeElement) return
  container.focus()
}

const decrement = () => {
  const prevValue = Number(valueEl.textContent)
  setValue(prevValue - 1)
}

const increment = () => {
  const prevValue = Number(valueEl.textContent)
  setValue(prevValue + 1)
}

container.addEventListener("click", () => {
  focus()
})

buttonDecrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  decrement()
})

buttonIncrement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  increment()
})

container.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
  if (ev.key === "ArrowLeft" || ev.key === "ArrowDown") {
    ev.preventDefault()
    decrement()
  }
})

container.addEventListener("keydown", (ev) => {
  if (ev.key === "ArrowRight" || ev.key === "ArrowUp") {
    ev.preventDefault()
    increment()
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  --size: 32px;

  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: var(--size);

  border: 2px solid;

  outline: none;
}

#container::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  background: currentColor;
  opacity: 0;
}

#container:focus-visible::before {
  opacity: 0.12;
}

.value-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

[data-value] {
  min-width: var(--size);
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}

.controls-button {
  position: relative;
  width: var(--size);
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.controls-button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  content: "";
  background: currentColor;
  opacity: 0;
}

.controls-button:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.08;
}

.controls-button:active::before {
  opacity: 0.16;
}
```

```html
<label for="container">Stepper control</label>
<span id="container" tabindex="0" role="spinbutton">
  <button
    data-action="decrement"
    class="controls-button"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-label="Decrease"
  >
    &lt;
  </button>

  <span class="value-wrapper">
    <span data-value> 0 </span>
  </span>

  <button
    data-action="increment"
    class="controls-button"
    tabindex="-1"
    aria-label="Increase"
  >
    &gt;
  </button>
</span>
```

---

I apologize for the large question. I felt that it was most logical to keep everything together, rather than trying to split it into multiple questions.
If folks want it split up / narrowed down, I can try. Just state so clearly.

Answer (score 2):

#### Introduction: Is a custom control really needed ? Isn't there an existing control that already do what you need ?

When talking about accessibility of user interfaces in general, this is the first question you should ask yourself. Using a standard control provide a lot of advantages, ammong the following:

- No need to reinvent the wheel, you have much less work to do, no need to maintain your custom control to keep it working as the time pass
- Accessibility of standard controls is in principle guaranteed everywhere, and if not, is going to improver over time, without the need for you to do anything

When you make your own control, even with all the good will you have, you are very likely to make something that isn't as accessible as standard controls.
Even if you use custom controls provided by whatever library, even well known ones, accessibility often don't get as much attention as it should.

Believe me, you can't beat standard controls. As a screen reader user myself, my own experience is, unfortunately, quite pessimistic, even for libraries that are used a lot and promoted by major companies.

So, ideally, you should only make custom controls **when standard controls *functionally* don't fullfill your needs**. I especially stress on the **functionality**, the feature: what does the control allow the user to do? what kind of data the user has to input?
Because if the problem is only a question of visual design, you are normally able to do whatever you want with CSS. Ideally, **you shouldn't create a custom control just because of the visual appearence of the standard equivalent**.

The W3C/WAI and the ARIA group have compiled a whole list of the most common usages, and the controls or pattern they correspond to. 95% of the time, you don't need to go custom.
See for example [that list of ARIA roles on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles). For most of the roles, there exists an element that implements it natively.

#### Back to your specific case

IF we ask the above question in your specific case, the answer is clearly no, you don't need a custom control, because what you are trying to do already exists.
What you are doing is a **spin control**.
A spin control is a control that allows the user to enter a number, whether directly by typing it, or by incrementing/decrementing it.

In HTML, you create a spin control by using the number input type:

```
<input type="number" value="50" min="0" max="100" step="1"/>
```

That's it. No hastle, and itt works everywhere.

#### IF you still want to make your custom control

IF you still want to go for your custom control, let's answer your initial questions.

In your case, the adequate ARIA role is [spinbutton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/spinbutton_role). That page also expain the differences with several other roles, and again recommend yoou to use `<input type="number"/>`.

This previous link also tells you what to do about focus: only the text field, or in your case only the span containing the value, should be focusable. The buttons shouldn't be focusable, as the functionality is already provided through up/down arrow keys.

As you have noticed, making the container focusable is bad, since it makes the screen reader uselessly read the increment/decrement buttons.

For labelling the control, refer to aria-label / aria-labelledby attributes. They will work if you define a role for your element.

For NVDA which don't let you take arrow keys for your own controls, it should no longer occur if you correctly set the spinbutton role, and well implement the corresponding functionality.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify: this isn't necessarily only for numbers; that was just an example. There are some cases where other values (such as a set of choices) would be used. However, numbers are definitely the primary case. If I used a standard input, one thing I would like is to disable typing a value manually; is that possible? Also, can the spin buttons of a standard number input be customized to be on either side of the value, always visible, and with custom content (SVGs, in this case)? Thanks for your time and input!

Comment: Why do you want to disable manual typing? Do you really want to force the user to press 50 times the + button? You are just complicating users' life. Please give me only one valid reason to do this, I'm curious to know.  This is the same combat with date picker which don't allow directly typing a date. That's just a nightmare.

Comment: If your data is not of number type, there are other more suitable common controls. For example for days of week, why not using a `<select>`? Bonus point: it's often possible to type the first letter of an option to directly select it. There is also `<datalist>` working with an input.

Comment: The primary case is a collection of controls for a song chord sheet viewer. There is a control each for text size, scroll speed (for automatic scroll), and transpose amount. The text size has a step size of 2, a lower bound of 2, and no upper bound, but shouldn't ever need to go above about 40. The scroll speed has a step size of 5 (although that may be changed soon), a lower bound of 5, and no upper bound, but shouldn't ever need to go above about 50. The transpose has a step size of 1, a lower bound of -11, an upper bound of 11, and wraps back to zero when crossing a bound.

Comment: Although there is some desktop use, the app is predominantly used on mobile. To be clear, I am not against allowing typed input. There are two original reasons: the first was (likely overly) strict requirements for valid values and step sizes; the second was that the implementation for the stepper was value agnostic: it simply displayed the value and emitted events for decrementing and incrementing; the consumer decided what to do on these inputs. The final logic was rather abstracted, with there being the stepper control, a wrapper component, and a data controller that exposed actions.

Comment: So, it mainly comes down to the structure of the existing codebase. The stepper was not intended to handle the values itself, only notifying the controller of requested changes. The controller is also used by separate keyboard hotkeys, and potentially touch gestures in the future, so it's not that simple to change. Although, if the touch gestures are implemented as continuous, sliding gestures, instead of a swipe/tap per increment/decrement, it may be a case to put in the work to change the controller to instead take raw values and normalize them.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the above.

Comment: I haven't tested what happens when step!=1, but it shouldn't be a problem to round to an integral number of steps after the user typed a value (for example on blur). For the rest, it was just a bad design, it's never easy to change it, but never too late either. Don't worry, we are always smarter afterwards. At least now you know how you could do better for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

@QuentinC has some good info in their answer.

To address a few specific questions you had

> tabindex="0" on the container and -1 on the buttons seems to work, but there is likely more to it that I'm missing.

It's almost that simple, except for your nested interactive element question which I address in the next paragraph. Take a look at the [spinbutton design pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/spinbutton/) and the [example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/spinbutton/examples/datepicker-spinbuttons/). They are setting `tabindex="0"` on the "value" of the spinbutton and `tabindex="-1"` on the increment/decrement buttons.

> Then there's the issue of nested interactive elements, etc. I'm not sure what the "correct" behavior is.

Nested interactive elements are typically not allowed from an HTML spec perspective.  The previously mentioned spinbutton design pattern has the increment/decrement buttons as *siblings* of the spinbutton value, so there aren't any nested elements.  You'll want your `<span data-value>0</span>` to have `tabindex="0"`.

> I experimented with adding keyboard event listeners (in conjunction with tabindex="0" on the element), but when using a screen reader (NVDA, specifically) the events were consumed by it instead of triggering the event listener

A screen reader has two modes of operation: (1) browse mode and (2) forms mode.  (Different terms might be used by different screen readers for the two modes.)  Browse mode is when you press a key and the screen reader has first shot at that key, such as the arrow keys, as you noticed.  Forms mode is when the browser has first shot at the key, which is what you want when the focus is on your element.

When you <kbd>TAB</kbd> through a page and land on interative elements, the screen reader will automatically (by default) switch between the two modes if that interactive element requires keyboard input more than just the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.  For example, tabbing to a link will **not** switch modes because you don't have to type so it'll remain in browser mode, although pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on the link will activate it.  If you tab to an <input>, the mode will switch so that you can type into the input.

A spinbutton will automatically switch modes, whether you use a native spinbutton or if you have a custom one as long as your custom element has [`role="spinbutton"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#spinbutton). That will allow the up/down events to go to your element.

> It should have labeling. Based on the docs for aria-label,

Yes, all interactive elements should have a label.  The design pattern example uses `<div role="group" aria-labelledby="id">` around the entire spinbutton group.

> I understand a role is required for this. However, I am not sure which to use.

Yes, `role="spinbutton"` as mentioned above so that the screen reader will switch modes automatically for you and allow the arrow key events to be sent to your element.

> A screen reader should read the value when focusing it, but not list the buttons. Just using aria-hidden on the buttons seems to work.

Yes, `aria-hidden` will prevent it from being read by the screen reader but you also need `tabindex="-1"` so that the screen reader user can't <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the element, otherwise nothing will be announced when they TAB to it.

> The new value should be read out it is updated. I believe aria-live is enough?

You *could* use `aria-live` but if your element has focus and you update the `aria-valuenow` attribute, the new value will be announced for "free".  You don't have to do anything to force the announcement.

Comment: Great answer! I found most of the same in my later research, but thanks very much for writing this up, and especially for that design patter amd example. The MDN docs for the `spinbutton` role include examples, including the sibling pattern and  `aria-valuenow`. I also found out about the two screen reader modes from a bug report to NVDA that turned out to simply be the modes. However, the arrow keys still didn't work for, even with the role set; I'll see if it's something to do with the nested interactive elements or what.

Comment: I'll edit my question sometime (Monday at earliest) to include my further research and experiments.

Comment: When the screen reader switches between modes, you typically hear an audible notification. For NVDA, it's kind of a "blink" and "bonk" sound between the two (hard to describe with words). I tried a simple test with a `<button>` (will not cause a mode change) and `<div tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="10">` and when I tabbed to the <div>, it made the switch sound, which causes keyboard events to be sent to the <div>.